# How to fix UISearchBar flick animation while transitioning view controllers?

Tags: ios11, uisearchcontroller, preferslargetitles

From iOS 11 (and above) i try to incorporate large titles (with `UISearchController`). One of my screen doesn't have a `UITableView` as first child on the hierarchy (but rather `UIPageViewController`, this cause that the navigationBar is not collapsed because the `scrollView` is not the first child.. but due to structure design can't.. anyway that's not an issue).

When another screen is pushed (and that screen has `navigationItem`'s `largeTitleDisplayMode` set to `never`), the transition animation looks weird (the `UISearchBar` is closed from the center and is not in sync with the navigationBar animation).

Note: If the controller that is pushed has `largeTitleDisplayMode` set to `.automatic` (or `always`) the transition is ok.

**Background**

When the `prefersLargeTitle` is enabled, `navigationItem`'s `searchController` is set and the first view on the hierarchy is not a tableView (or i guess scrollView descendent), the navigationBar shows the searchBar open.

**Options Tried**

I tried modifying the `translucent` property of the `UINavigationBar` and `UISearchBar`. Also set the UINavigationBar's `clipToBounds`.

**Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    }

}
```

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }

}
```

[image]